# How to debug .datepicker()

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page with some date fields on. On document load, I call .datepicker() on them and it works great.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".date").datepicker();
    })
</script>
```

I have another partial page which is loaded into a div after an event on the page.

The page it is loading contains the following code.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        alert($(".ajaxdiv .date").length);
        // This is fired when the div is populated
        //   so I know this block is firing and that the date fields are being selected

        $(".ajaxdiv .date").datepicker();
        // This appears to do nothing
    })
</script>
```

My question is not **why isn't this working?** so I haven't tried to supply code, but **how can I debug this and identify the problem myself using chrome?**

I don't know enough about datepicker() to know where it is going wrong. How can I tell if the "binding" has worked.

Any input you can offer is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to put your init of your datepicker into $( document ).ready(), which will make sure that DOM is ready for javascript code to execute ?

Comment: $(function(){ ... }) is the same as $(document).ready(function(){ ... })

Comment: @Beakie did you end up resolving this? Have the exact same issue. It's working on about 6 other pages but my new page wont fire. no errors. console.log() shows we're getting to that part of the code. can't figure it out

Answer (score -2):

You need to init it as soon as DOM is ready

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="#datePicker">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
   <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#datePicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I had using $(function(){  })

Comment: The code is firing, it kicks out the alert. It just doesn't work on datepicker().

Comment: @Beakie learning something every day  .. thanks for the heads up, that ($function and $(document).ready are the same.. Didn't know :)